# calling a dict from python to a basic macro in openoffice

Tags: python, json, libreoffice-basic

From a Basic macro, I launch a Python script that returns a json input as following :

```
{
    u'commande': {
        u'nom_commande': u'TEST PANIER EXPRESS', 
        u'statut_commande': u'prepa', 
        u'numero': u'712', 
        u'note': u"test \xe0 l'arriv\xe9e de autobus.", 
        u'id_commande': u'17', u'maj_commande': u'2013-01-18 10:56:28'
    }
}
```

My problem is to retrieve the datas in basic. I always have this error :

> list or dict object has no attribute gettypes traceback follows

It seems that my script cannot return anything else than a string. Is it a way to receive a dict or a list?

Thank you very much for any answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a python script should return a tuple (containing tuples). Then Basic can manage the python's return as it was an Array.

[This post was very helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591656/how-can-i-call-a-python-macro-in-a-cell-formula-in-openoffice-org-calc)