# Calling a python function from within LibreCalc

Tags: python, function, add-in, user-defined-functions, libreoffice-calc

I have the following code inside a file called calculadora.py

```
def calcpy(numA,numB):
    return numA+numB
```

Which is the proper way of calling the function calcpy() from within LibreCalc? I'd like to put, say, in cell `A1=calcpy(B1,C1)` and obtain the result...

I've already put the python script in both `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/python/` and `/home/lucas/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python`, I can also see it under the menu Tools->Macro->Organize Macro->Python

[image]

... but I do not really know how to invoke that function.

I've read some posts where it was suggested to wrap the function inside Basic, such as this:

```
function calcpy(a as double, b as double) as double
    script = GetScript("calcpy")
    calcpy = script.invoke(Array(a, b), Array(), Array())
end function
```

... but whenever I do use =calcpy(5,4) I get an error saying: "BASIC runtime error. Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined."

Is this even possible? Is using Basic the proper way? Is there a more direct (elegant?) way of doing it?

Thanks,

Lucas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good answer here: [How can I call a Python macro in a cell formula in OpenOffice.Org Calc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591656/how-can-i-call-a-python-macro-in-a-cell-formula-in-openoffice-org-calc)   In your case,  the Basic code should be:

```vb
function calcpy(a as double, b as double) as double
    Dim scriptPro As Object, myScript As Object
    scriptPro = ThisComponent.getScriptProvider()
    myScript = scriptPro.getScript( _
           "vnd.sun.star.script:calculadora.py$calcpy?language=Python&location=user")
    calcpy = myScript.invoke(Array(a, b), Array(), Array() )
end function
```

Yes, there is a more direct / elegant way: [Create an Add-In](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/Add-In/Python_How-To).