# Simple python user defined function in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: python, vba, user-defined-functions, libreoffice

**Question.**
I would like to create simple user defined function (UDF) using python for LibreOffice Calc:

```
def MySum(a, b, c):
    s = a+b+c
    return s
```

Most likely answer will involve some non-python technicalities, so I want reference to some quick-start guide about what they are and how to use them.

**My research.**

1. There was a similar question:
   https://superuser.com/questions/1297120/use-a-python-function-as-formula-in-libreoffice-calc-cells.
   and
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0t7tkwL1Nk
   It was too complicated to comprahend, and function there used static cells, I want them to be any cells.
2. I found that one of the methods to use python functions in LO Calc is by creating Add-In:
   https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/Add-In/Python_How-To
   It involved some non-python IDE code withour any quick-start reference about how to understand and write code like this.
3. Also I found that python scripts can be run in Calc using APSO:
   [Basic Wrapper for LibreOffice Calc Python UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833486/basic-wrapper-for-libreoffice-calc-python-udf)
4. One more similar question:
   [Calling a python function from within LibreCalc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336699/calling-a-python-function-from-within-librecalc)
   I wasn't able to comprehend it.
5. I found that some of LO Basic terminology, which is used to create python macro, is covered here:
   https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/CG4.1/PDF/CG4112-CalcMacros.pdf
   and here
   https://wiki.openoffice.org/w/images/d/d4/0300CS33-CalcGuide.pdf

I wasn't satisfied with this answers. Either answers weren't complete or too complicated or there were a lot of non-python commands without reference to some guide that would explain what they are. Also most of the information was posted long time ago.

**Update. My attempt.**
I tried to replicate actions done in first post. So I did this in APSO console:

```
    def VOL(a, b, c):
    v = a*b*c
    return v

    def call_vol():
        oSheet = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getSheets().getByIndex(0)
        cell_a = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
        cell_b = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A2")
        cell_c = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A3")
        cell_result = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("B1")
        cell_result.setValue(
            VOL(
                cell_a.getValue(),
                cell_b.getValue(),
                cell_c.getValue()))
    
    g_exportedScripts = call_vol,
```

And I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'call_vol' is not defined
>>> portedScripts = call_vol,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'call_vol' is not defined
>>>
```

**P.S.** I am chemist, so many things you find ridiculously simple may be inaccessibly hard to comprehend for me. So be simple.

Comment: In cases like this where the information has already been thoroughly discussed, the only way is probably going to be for you yourself to come up with an answer that you're happy with. *"ridiculously simple"* — no one is saying this is easy; implementing a python UDF will require some effort. But you have some decisions to make, such as, do you want to use APSO, which makes it convenient to edit files? And do you want to tackle creating an add-in, or go the easier route of using a Basic wrapper.

Comment: *"function there used static cells, I want them to be any cells."* — I'm not sure what you mean by this. The example was `=VOL(A1, A2, B3)`, and those cell references will automatically be changed by Calc when the formula is dragged to fill. *"It was too complicated to comprahend"* — If you want further help, you'll have to explain what parts you were able to understand and where you got stuck. Your post is somewhat good in that it gives good links, but not so good because it doesn't tell specifically what you want to know, such as, what *"non-python technicalities"* are you wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to replicate actions done in first post. So I did this in APSO console.

From those two statements alone, it sounds like you barely even looked at the first post. It says:

> Once it is installed, go to *Tools -> Macros -> Organize python scripts.* Expand My Macros and go to *Menu -> Create module*. Name it "custom_functions.py".

Why you thought to put all of that code into the console I have no idea, but if one were to do that, there are at least two problems:

1. Copy and paste into that console doesn't seem to maintain indentation, so you would need to enter it all by typing or line by line instead of pasting the whole block. That's why the error shows that `call_vol` is not defined. Python requires correct indentation to define its structure, unlike languages such as Java.
2. The console will not store the code. It needs to be stored in either `user`, `share`, or `document` so that the UDF wrapper can find it. Also, `g_exportedScripts` indicates which functions to export from a module to be called from *Tools → Macros → Run Macro*. A module in python is synonymous with a text file containing code.

Anyway, here is a [user-defined function](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/guide/userdefined_function.html) to call that code.

```
Function Call_VOL(a,b,c)
    Dim oScriptProvider, oScript
    oScriptProvider = ThisComponent.getScriptProvider()
    oScript = oScriptProvider.getScript(_
        "vnd.sun.star.script:custom_functions.py$VOL?language=Python&location=user")
    Call_VOL = oScript.invoke(array(a,b,c), array(), array())
End Function
```

Then for example enter `=CALL_VOL(1;2;3)` into a cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: APSO does not support REPL Command Line Processing [issue](https://gitlab.com/jmzambon/apso/-/issues/27) - feel free to support request.